# JAVA | CXF | JAX-RS | Exception handling

Tags: java, exception, cxf, jax-rs

We are using cxf version 2.5.2 and we expose and consume couple of restful web services using cxf jaxrs.

Any idea how to throw exceptions from server to client ? 
I tried defining a custom exception mapper by implementing ExceptionMapper interface (toResponse method) and added the bean in cxf jaxrs:server providers list.

Client side : Implemented ResponseExceptionMapper (fromResonse method) and added the bean in cxf jaxrs:client providers list. But this doesnt seem to work.

Exception is a custom exception that extends java.lang.Exception.
Got "IllegalAnnotationsException 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor"

Found http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-814 and upgrading to jaxb-impl 2.2.5 resolved that issue.

But at the end, i am struck with the following exception in server side (during client invocation) :

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider :
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions blueprints.common.util.BlueprintsException does not have a no-arg default constructor"
```

and in client side :

```
JAXBException occurred : 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.helpers.LoadingByteArrayOutputStream$1 cannot be cast to  myExceptionClass:java.lang.ClassCastException" when i typecast Response.getEntity()) tp myExceptionClass in fromResponse (jaxrs provider that implements ResponseExceptionMapper)
```

Has anybody else faced similar issues? 
Do we need to add custom out interceptors ? The cxf doc doesnt provide example for exception handling using spring config.

Edit based on jigar's comment:
After adding default constructor, the entity in response contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<blueprintsServiceException>
<stackTrace/>
<stackTrace/>
<stackTr‌​ace/>
<stackTrace/>
...
</blueprintsServiceException>`
```

and i still get java.lang.ClassCastException:

```
org.apache.cxf.helpers.LoadingByteArrayOutputStream$1 cannot be cast to blueprints.server.exception.BlueprintsServiceException' when i typecast Response.getEntity()) to myExceptionClass in fromResponse 
(jaxrs provider that implements ResponseExceptionMapper)
```

Thanks,
Gayathri

Answer (score 0):

in `BlueprintsException` you need to provide a default constructor,

You might have overloaded the constructor which hides the default constructor, So you need to provide  default constructor explicitly

Comment: Thanks for the response. After adding default constructor, the entity in response contains '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><blueprintsServiceException><stackTrace/><stackTrace/><stackTrace/><stackTrace/>...</blueprintsServiceException> and i still get
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.helpers.LoadingByteArrayOutputStream$1 cannot be cast to blueprints.server.exception.BlueprintsServiceException' when i typecast Response.getEntity()) to myExceptionClass in fromResponse (jaxrs provider that implements ResponseExceptionMapper)